# delete multiple records from wordpress database with multiple checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I created a customer table in Wordpress database that name "tblvessel". The code below select the records from the database and display the records as a table with the "checkbox" on each records, and also assign the record's 'ID' to each the "checkbox" value.

I want user able to delete multiple records from wordpress database by checking the 'checkbox'.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-left: 0">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ETA</th>
                <th>Vessel type</th>
                <th>Vessel</th>             
                <th>Flag</th>
                <th>Origin</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th>Arrival/Departure</th>
                <th>Remark</th>
                <th>User</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            global $wpdb;
            $today  =   date('Ymd');

            $todayuploads = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM tblvessel WHERE upload_date = $today ORDER BY date DESC, type, vessel, av_dp ASC" );

            foreach ( $todayuploads as $todayupload )   {

                $id = $todayupload->id;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="vschbox[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
                    <td><?php echo date_format(date_create($todayupload->date), 'd/m/Y' ); ?> <?php echo $todayupload->eta_etd; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php 
                        $conv_type = $todayupload->type;
                        switch ($conv_type) {
                            case 1:
                               echo "Container Barges";
                               break;
                            case 2:
                               echo "General Cargo Barges";
                               break;
                            case 3:
                               echo "Tourist Vessel";
                               break;
                            case 4:
                               echo "Motor Tanker";
                               break;                           
                            default:
                                echo "Invalid Vessel Type";
                        }
                        ?>                      
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $todayupload->vessel;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $todayupload->flag;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $todayupload->origin;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $todayupload->destination;?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php 
                        $conv_avdp = $todayupload->av_dp;
                        switch ($conv_avdp) {
                            case 1:
                               echo "Arrival";
                               break;
                            case 2:
                               echo "Departure";
                               break;                                       
                            default:
                                echo "Invalid Arrival/Departure Type";
                        }
                        ?>                      
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $todayupload->remark;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $todayupload->user;?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
            } 
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <form action="" method="post" id="deletedataform">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-info pull-right" style="width:100px; margin-bottom:10px;" />
    </form>

</div>

<?php
global $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $checkbox = $_POST['vschbox'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i]; 

        $message = "Data deleted successfully !";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: When you do `POST` method for example to (delete all), you will receive array of checked checkboxes. Then run DELETE command with IN keyword.

Comment: I have problem about receive array of checked checkboxes, it's say "Undefined index: vschbox".

<?php

global $wpdb;

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){

    $checkbox = $_POST['vschbox'];

    for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){

        $del_id = $checkbox[$i]; 

        $message = "Data deleted successfully !";

    }

}
?>

Comment: Any why is table NOT inside form?

Comment: ...oop, didn't see that. i'm gonna try the IN keyword for really qiuck

Comment: sorry, I'm a newbie, I don't know how that keyword work, I try to use this "$wpdb->delete( 'table', $del_id );" instead, but it's not working.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/85946/use-of-in-clause-within-a-delete-command-mysql

Comment: Thanks, it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
********Big Thanks to "tilz0r" in the comments.**********
***I'm new here, don't know how to close my asked question, so I'll leave a answer here.***
**In case "tilz0r" post the answer, I'll Mark "tilz0r" post as the correct answer**

<?php
global $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $checkbox = $_POST['vschbox'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i]; 
        $wpdb->query( 
            "DELETE FROM tblvessel
             WHERE id IN($del_id)
            "       
        );

        $message = "Data deleted successfully !";
    }
}
?>

<div class="container" style="padding-left: 0">
    <form action="" method="post" id="deletedataform">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>ETA</th>
                    <th>Vessel type</th>
                    <th>Vessel</th>             
                    <th>Flag</th>
                    <th>Origin</th>
                    <th>Destination</th>
                    <th>Arrival/Departure</th>
                    <th>Remark</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                global $wpdb;
                $today  =   date('Ymd');

                $todayuploads = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM tblvessel WHERE upload_date = $today ORDER BY date DESC, type, vessel, av_dp ASC" );

                foreach ( $todayuploads as $todayupload )   {

                    $id = $todayupload->id;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="vschbox[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></td>
                        <td><?php echo date_format(date_create($todayupload->date), 'd/m/Y' ); ?> <?php echo $todayupload->eta_etd; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <?php 
                            $conv_type = $todayupload->type;
                            switch ($conv_type) {
                                case 1:
                                   echo "Container Barges";
                                   break;
                                case 2:
                                   echo "General Cargo Barges";
                                   break;
                                case 3:
                                   echo "Tourist Vessel";
                                   break;
                                case 4:
                                   echo "Motor Tanker";
                                   break;                           
                                default:
                                    echo "Invalid Vessel Type";
                            }
                            ?>                      
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $todayupload->vessel;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $todayupload->flag;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $todayupload->origin;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $todayupload->destination;?></td>
                        <td>
                            <?php 
                            $conv_avdp = $todayupload->av_dp;
                            switch ($conv_avdp) {
                                case 1:
                                   echo "Arrival";
                                   break;
                                case 2:
                                   echo "Departure";
                                   break;                                       
                                default:
                                    echo "Invalid Arrival/Departure Type";
                            }
                            ?>                      
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $todayupload->remark;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $todayupload->user;?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                } 
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-info pull-right" style="width:100px; margin-bottom:10px;" />
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: running a query in a loop is bad. sine you are using `WHERE id IN (...)` you should just construct the SQL in the loop and run the query once.

Answer (score 0):

*It can be like this*

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$ids=[1,4,7,9];
$ids = implode(',', $ids);
$wpdb->query( 
    "DELETE FROM tblvessel
     WHERE id IN($ids)"     
);
```